# How to convert my loop into a function that I can call anytime

Tags: python-3.x, function

Good day. I have this snippet as a part of my script. I wanted to convert this into a function as this snippet is called a few times.

```
query = string-to-search-variable
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=5, stop=5, pause=2):
    res = get_tld(j, as_object=True) 
    print("          " + "\t" + res.fld, end=" ")
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide sample for this function - eg. input and expected output - the way you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this so you can just call res_function(query)?

```
def res_function(query):
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=5, stop=5, pause=2):
        res = get_tld(j, as_object=True)
        print("          " + "\t" + res.fld, end=" ")
```